# Sending IOS apps though email an running it on a simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I am new at IOS development.
I would like to know if there is a way to send a app by Email and run it on a simulated?
So I need 2 things.
1. How to send the app by Email? 
2. Where can I download a IPhone simulator?

(I come from android development, so I need something like that .apk )

Thanks,
Ilan

Answer (score 2):

you cant just export an apk and run it in any device, in iOS you would need to add the device you want to deploy the app on to your Developer Portal/Devices, and make a provisioning profile for it, download the profile then archive your app as Ad-hoc, you will get an ipa file instead of apk you could email that to your friend

Comment: Can he run it on a simulator? Or does he need a mac/iphone/ipod?

Comment: for simulators i don't think so, but you should always have friends who own an iphone :>

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible. One cannot install App on the Simulator. This only works with the source code via Xcode.

Welcome in the world of iOS development. :)

Comment: Crap... So if i need to send a coworker the app, he needs to have a Mac and xcode? That's the only way?

Comment: If he/she doesn't have an iOS device, yes, this is the only way.